# Center Page On Dynamic Table Cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

The scenario: I have a dynamic table that exceeds the window size (it's huge, 100x100 cells 150px tall and wide), and I have disabled scrolling on the page.

The purpose: I'm trying to make it so that when you click on a `td` cell, javascript grabs the body coordinates (window coordindates would be wrong), and moves the table so that the cell you clicked on is smack dead as center in the screen as it will get (it's a map that you "walk" on if that helps clarify why I disabled scrolling).

The try: here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JS8eB/) of my code. As you can see, I don't think `window.scrollTo` is doing what I want, it simply scrolls down the page. How can I make the cell I click on move the table so that it's like I scrolled to that cell?

The code:

```
function centerCell() {
    window.scrollTo(this.offsetLeft,this.offsetTop);
}
function genDivs(divs){ 
    var root = document.createElement("table");
    for(var x = 0; x <= divs; x++){ 
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for(var y = 0; y <= divs; y++){ 
            var cell = document.createElement("td"); 
            cell.textContent = x+","+y;
            cell.addEventListener("click",centerCell,false);
            row.appendChild(cell); 
        } 
        root.appendChild(row); 
    }
    root.style.width=String(divs*150)+"px";
    root.style.height=String(divs*150)+"px";
    var main = document.getElementById("container");
    main.appendChild(root);
}
genDivs(100);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed some updates to your `centerCell` function and I changed some of your css:

JS:

```
function centerCell() {
    var w2 = this.offsetWidth / 2,
        h2 = this.offsetHeight / 2;
    var t = this.offsetTop + h2,
        l = this.offsetLeft + w2;
    var w = window.innerWidth / 2,
        h = window.innerHeight / 2;
    window.scrollTo(l - w, t - h);
}
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/2gdCz/
Full Page Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwertynl/2gdCz/show/

Comment: Works perfectly, I wish I could give you more than one upvote lol